# How to set the minimum quantity of product by category in woocomerce using mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been looking into the database schema of woocommerce and see how to change the minimum of quantity of products under a category but this is too difficult to locate. I want to use a MYSQL query to change the minimum of all products under a category.

example:

```
 Product      |  Category   | Minimum Quantity
 T-shirt      - Clothing    - 20
 Polo         - Clothing    - 30
 Long Sleeves - Clothing    - 50
 Back Packs   - Bags        - 50
 Gymn Bags    - Bags        - 20
```

The above products  under clothing contain different quantity. Now, I want to set the minimum of all products by category the same as 50.

Does anybody know this?

Comment: you want to update all the product quantity category wise?

Comment: Provide sample table data, what you tried so far and what is expected as output.

Comment: Please check my new edit.,